# Call another page from current page

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

Goal is to develop simple system that provides switching between several pages. `MainWindow` has a few functions which are redirecting to them pages looking like this:

```
private void BtnDebug_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   FrContent.Content = new Page_Debug();
}
```

This works only if function is called from `MainWindow`. The desire is to call them from `Page` aswell.

**SOLUTIONS TRIED**

```
private readonly MainWindow _mainWindow = new MainWindow();

private void BtnShowNotes_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _mainWindow.FrContent.Content = new Page_Notes();
}
```

Switched page doesn't show any elements although it called `InitializeComponent()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `MainWindow`. You should access the `Frame` of the already existing window. You could get a reference to this one using the `Application.Current.Windows` property:

```
private void BtnShowNotes_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mw = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (mw != null)
        mw.FrContent.Content = new Page_Notes();
}
```